# How do I search for all authors, affiliations, and citations for a specific journal ISSN using Scopus API and Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, api

I have never used an API before, but I am trying to learn how to use Scopus for a project I'm doing with a few colleagues. I have gotten about this far:

```
response = requests.get("https://api.elsevier.com/content/search/scopus/",
                           headers={'Accept':'application/json',
                                 'X-ELS-APIKey': '[My_API_Key]'})
```

I keep getting a 400 error in response to this, even though my API Key is valid, and I've entered it correctly. I'm guessing I'm getting the error because the query is too large since I am just searching Scopus instead of looking for any specific author ID or ISSN.

I want to run queries to get all of the author data for a handful of specific ISSNs. As someone who is very uncomfortable using Python (I'm a web developer, not a Python programmer) and also someone who has never used an API themselves, I have no idea how to proceed from here. I've read the guides provided by Elsevier, but as I don't understand this stuff, I haven't found them helpful at all. I've also watched and read some tutorials about APIs, but none of them have helped me figure out how to make an actual specific request.

If any of you have used Scopus before, can you please tell me how to make a request based on the parameters I need? Am I supposed to put the ISSN at the end of the URL? If so, how should I format it, and how do I specify what other data I want for that specific ISSN?

I apologize for the lack of specificity in this particular question, I am just completely lost here. I am currently using Jupyter notebooks to write and run my code.

Comment: I think that you're on the right track. You've identified the 400 error which indicates a malformed request (see: https://dev.elsevier.com/documentation/ScopusSearchAPI.wadl) . 

There are still too many unknowns to offer more advice at this time. I would focus in on the request and get that right so that at least you are not getting a 400 error.   I think that an obvious issue is that your request doesn't seem to show 'what' you want to search for!  It just shows that you want to hit the Scopus search endpoint, provides your API Key but it doesn't give any paramerters like the ISSN.

Answer (score 0):

As other responders have said you are on the right track, however, your query is essentially blank, in that you are not actually asking the API for anything.

This request

```
"https://api.elsevier.com/content/serial/title/issn/[ISSN]?apiKey=[My_API_Key]"
```

will bring back general metadata about an ISSN, but to go deep with author and institution metadata, you should start with a Scopus Search API query:

```
"https://api.elsevier.com/content/search/scopus?query=issn([ISSN])?apiKey=[My_API_Key]"
```

The API Docs page, located here:

```
"https://dev.elsevier.com/api_docs.html"
```

Has more tech details about the APIs